# Auto close modal dialog - After server code is done, close dialog in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, showmodaldialog

I have a Google Sheet that runs some Apps Script server code to connect to an SQL server.  I want to show the message "loading..." in the modal dialog while data is being refreshed.  I can get the modal to pop up, but I want to auto-close the dialog as soon as the code is finished.

An example I have set up is:

```
function testpop () {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<p> This box will close when the data has finished loading.</p>')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setWidth(250)
    .setHeight(200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Loading...');
  sleep(1000);
//close the dialog
}
```

I know this can be called on a client side but need it to be handled in the GS so it fires when the code is done.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The flow of events could be:

- User does something
- Triggers modal dialog
- `onLoad` event of modal dialog triggers client side code
- Client side `google.script.run` triggers a server side `.gs` function to run
- Server function in `.gs` script file runs.
- database updated from server.
- server code sends a return value back to dialog
- "withSuccessHandler()" in dialog detects the return from the server
- "withSuccessHandler()" runs and closes the dialog using `google.script.host.close();`

You'll need a `<script>` tag in your modal dialog.

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {    
    //console.log('window.onload ran!');

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(closeDialog)
      .theFunctionNameToUpdateDatabase()
  };

  window.closeDialog = function() {
    google.script.host.close();
  };
</script>
```

Right now you are using:

```
HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(the HTML here)
```

You could create the HTML from a file instead:

```
HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
```

Answer (score 19):

//show dialog

```
var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Please wait...</b>');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(output, 'Saving...');
```

some code

//close dialog

```
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<script>google.script.host.close();</script>');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(output, 'Loading...');
```

*optional

```
  ui.alert("Saved Successfully!")
```

Comment: I love this. I think its a cleaner solution. Thanks!

Comment: This is so much easier and robust than the (currently) accepted answer. All the points to you.

Comment: Excellent solution, even with gpt4, it can't give me a proper solution like this one :)

Answer (score 1):

I too went with the answer given by @pcw11211. I dressed it up a little by encapsulating the htmlmodalDialog call in a function that can either open or close a dialog. I added a little html styling in there too. Also note the try/catch around the htmlmodalDialog that is there so that the scrip can still run when you are testing from the script editor, otherwise the main script is sometimes(?) halted with a Context error.

```
/**
* HELPER FUNCTION : TO OPEN & CLOSE MODAL DIALOGUE
*/
function htmlmodalDialog(title, text, close){
 var htmlText = '<div>' + text + '</div>';
 htmlText += '<style type="text/css">';
 htmlText += 'body{text-align: center; font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;}';
 htmlText += 'div{margin: auto;}';
 htmlText += '</style>';
 if(close){htmlText += '<script>google.script.host.close();</script>';}
 var htmlOutput = HtmlService
  .createHtmlOutput(htmlText)
  .setHeight(60)
  .setWidth(200);
try {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, title);
}catch(e){
    Logger.log('function htmlmodalDialog(title, text, close)');
    Logger.log(e);
}
```

}

The function is called from the main code as follows with the last argument being an open/close boolean.

```
htmlmodalDialog('Starting', 'Working ...', false);
    
//do something here

htmlmodalDialog('Finished', 'Operation completed.', true);
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

This solution provides a button to close the dialog immediately and will close automatically after 5000 milliseconds (5 sec.) by using "onload="setTimeout(closer, 5000)" in the body tag.  It will pass a google script variable to the HTML to customize the dialog box.

Here's what I came up with...

My GS File:

```
function myGSFunction(inputVariable){  
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let gsVariable = inputVariable.toUpperCase().trim() || null;
  let htmlOutput;

        .
        .
        .
  htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('errorModelessDialog');
  htmlOutput.htmlVariable = gsVariable;  //define variable accessible in html
  ui.showModelessDialog(htmlOutput.evaluate().setWidth(400).setHeight(150), 'ERROR');
    .
    .
    .
};
```

My errorModelessDialog.html File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body onload="setTimeout(closer, 5000)">
    <p align="center"><?!=htmlVariable?> is not valid.</p>
    <p align="center"><button onclick="google.script.host.close()">Close</button></p>
    <script>
      function closer(){
        google.script.host.close();
      }
    </script>  
  </body>
</html>
```