# How do you close a modal on the server side since UiInstance.close() is deprecated

Tags: google-apps-script, modal-dialog

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String)

The current documentation shows that UiInstance.close() is deprecated. However, it doesn't explain how to close the dialog going forward. Is it no longer possible to close a modal from the server side?

This question is not referring to prompts but modals being opened using showModalDialog.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is stated in the document that you can use the [google.script.host.close()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#closing_dialogs_and_sidebars_in_google_apps) for closing. I found here a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527682/auto-close-modal-dialog) that use this to close a modal dialog. Just check it if it can help you.

Comment: `google.script.host.close()` works on the client side but it does not work on the server side. My question is related to closing the modal on the server side.

Comment: @dhan Yes so the answer is in front of you. call close from the client side as mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @SujayPhadke You're referring to how to close the modal from the client side. My question is how to close the modal from the server side.

Comment: @SujayPhadke Where in the docs does it say that you cannot do it? I haven't seen that.